# Is it allowed to hide/unhide an Admob ad with a timer?

Tags: java, android, admob

Is it allowed to manually hide/unhide the same **Admob Ad** after a certain time and does the ad need to be displayed for a particular time to count as an impression?

What i do is create a random int and  when the int is value 2 i display the ad for **15s** and then i set the visibility to invisible.

**My code:**

```
int randomIndex;
Random random = new Random();

randomIndex = random.nextInt(5);
Log.d(TAG,"randomIndex: "+randomIndex);

        if (randomIndex == 2) {
            if (mFrameLayoutBigAd.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                mFrameLayoutBigAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mFrameLayoutBigAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 15000);
            }
        }else{
            mFrameLayoutBigAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

**EDIT**

if the ad is set to be visible again i just load the old adrequest again, so i'm not making a new ad request.

Comment: According to documentation, it seems to be okay. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en

Comment: What u required?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can hide and show an ad, but there is a risk that the user will accidentally click when the ad reappears, which can be identified as click-inducing, which violates the AdMob guidelines.
Hope this helps.